# IF between WEEK() or MONTH() always return false

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to update some dates only when the new one is in a different WEEK() or MONTH() .

The query is the following:

```
$id = '1';
$currtime = time();

$myQuery = $db->prepare("
    INSERT INTO mytable (id, weekdate, monthdate) 
    VALUES (:id, :currtime, :currtime)
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE 
    weekdate = if(WEEK(weekdate, 1) <> WEEK(:currtime, 1), :currtime, weekdate),
    monthdate = if(MONTH(monthdate) <> MONTH(:currtime), :currtime, monthdate)
");

$myQuery->bindParam(':id', $id);
$myQuery->bindParam(':currtime', $currtime);
```

I don't get any error but it seems that the IF always return FALSE.

EDIT: After some testing I found that WEEK() and MONTH() always return null, how can I make the query work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The php `time()` function returns unix epoch time a la `1447270661`, while the mysql `week()`/`month()` functions take in mysql date values.

```
select curdate(),
       week(curdate()),
       week('2015-11-11'),
       week(FROM_UNIXTIME(1447270661));
#2015-11-11 45 45 45
```

You'll need to pass in the proper parameter value to the mysql functions. If you have a unix time, you can convert with `FROM_UNIXTIME`.